# How closely does Ikki Tousen match Romance of the Three Kingdoms?

Tags: ikkitousen

One of the pieces of character motivation in Ikki Tousen that I found interesting is that the characters get their powers from *magatamas*, basically stones containing the souls of people from the Romance of the Three Kingdoms. In exchange for this power, characters are (supposedly) cursed to play out the Romance of the Three Kingdoms again, taking the role of the person whose soul they carry; some characters are aware of this and deliberately try to avoid their RoTK fates.

Which RoTK characters do each of the major Ikki Tousen characters correspond to, and are there any ways in which the Ikki Tousen overall plot breaks from the RotK plot (ignoring trivial differences that don't affect the ultimate fate of notable characters)?

Note: This is specifically about the **manga**, not the anime.